# How to validate numeric value in c?

Tags: c

When I insert character value in array my program was exit. if I insert character value, I want to continue my loop without exit program and take next integer value. 
whats wrong in my code.

My code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main()
{
    int row1, col1, row2, col2, i, j, k, sum = 0;
    int first[10][10], second[10][10], multiply[10][10];
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter the no of rows and columns of first matrix\n");
    scanf("%d%d",&row1,&col1);
    printf("Enter the Element of first matrix");
    for(i=0;i<row1;i++){
        for(j=0;j<col1;j++){
            printf("\nEnter %d element %d row",j+1,i+1);
            scanf("%d",&first[i][j]);
            check = first[i][j];
            printf("%d",check);
            if(check>0 || check<0)
            {
                printf("this is digit \n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("this is not digit\n");
                printf("\nEnter %d element %d row",j+1,i+1);
                scanf("%d",&first[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Enter the no of rows and columns of second matrix\n");
    scanf("%d%d",&row2,&col2);

    if(col1 == row2){
        printf("Enter the Element of second matrix");
        for(i=0;i<row2;i++){
            for(j=0;j<col2;j++){
                printf("\nEnter %d element %d row",j+1,i+1);
                scanf("%d",&second[i][j]);
            }
        }

        for(i=0;i<row1;i++){
            for(j=0;j<col2;j++){
                for(k=0;k<row2;k++){
                    multiply[i][j]=sum;
                    sum=0;
                }
            }
        }
        printf("Multiplication of matrices=\n");
        for(i=0;i<row1;i++){
            for(j=0;j<col2;j++){
                multiply[i][j]=0;
                for(k=0;k<row1;k++){
                    multiply[i][j] += first[i][k] * second[k][j];
                }
                printf("%d\t",multiply[i][j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("You are incorrect. According to the requirement of matrix multiplication, the number of column of first matrix should equal to the number of rows of second matrix.");
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Thanking You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute

```
scanf("%d",&first[i][j])
```

This means that your `scanf` only accepts integers nothing else. if you enter an alphabetic characters then scanf will read nothing and then return 0 as value for `first[i][j]`

The next  `scanf("%d");` will be unable to get your input (even if they are numeric) because the stdin is not cleaned yet from the alphabetic characters.

Replace this

```
for(i=0;i<row1;i++){
        for(j=0;j<col1;j++){
            printf("\nEnter %d element %d row",j+1,i+1);
            scanf("%d",&first[i][j]);
```

by

```
for(i=0;i<row1;i++){
        for(j=0;j<col1;j++){
            printf("\nEnter %d element %d row",j+1,i+1);
            while (scanf("%d",&first[i][j]))<=0) {
                printf("this is not digit\n");
                printf("\nEnter %d element %d row",j+1,i+1);
                scanf("%*[^\n]"); // this clean your input buffer in case yhe input is not integer
            }
```

and remove this block:

```
            check = first[i][j];
            printf("%d",check);
            if(check>0 || check<0)
            {
                printf("this is digit \n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("this is not digit\n");
                printf("\nEnter %d element %d row",j+1,i+1);
                scanf("%d",&first[i][j]);
            }
```

Comment: Thanx Mohamed. This suggestion is helpful for me and also improve knowledge by description.

Answer (score 2):

`scanf` returns you the number of entries that were read successfully. When you try to read a number, but non-numeric value is supplied, `scanf` returns zero. You need to repeatedly prompt the user for the entry until `scanf` returns `1`. Here is one way to modify your code to do it:

```
for(;;) {
    printf("\nEnter %d element %d row",j+1,i+1);
    if (scanf("%d",&first[i][j]) == 1) break;
    // Read and ignore the invalid input. 's' means "string", '*' means "ignore".
    scanf("%*s");
    printf("\nThe data you entered was incorrect.");
}
```